# UICollectionView cells display weirdly - Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionviewcell, collectionview

I'm trying to display some cells in the `UICollectionView`, But please see the images attached and the code I've provided below, its very weird.

After days of research I didn't find a helpful answer. Please help. 
I'm displaying about 200 cells in a view. This is a weird phenomenon happens on the later half when scrolling.

Also, I only need identical size for all cells. Any insights will be appreciated.

![image2][https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEgGy.png]

![image1][https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKei3.png]

```
var inset = 2
var dividendWidth = 2 // Number of cells in a row
var dividendHeight = 5 // Number of rows in a visible "page"

func configureCellLayout() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    navHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height
    tabHeight = tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.height
    statusHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

    emptyViewWidth = screenSize.width - inset*(dividendWidth+1)
    emptyViewHeight = screenSize.height - navHeight - tabHeight - statusHeight - inset*(dividendHeight+1)

    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 2, 2, 2)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = inset
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = inset
    modifyDividend()
    let itemWidth: CGFloat = emptyViewWidth / dividendWidth
    let itemHeight: CGFloat = emptyViewHeight / dividendHeight
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight)
    collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
}
```

Comment: Can you please share more of your code?

Comment: @J.Koush Thanks for your reply! I've just discovered where the problem was. It was because I accidentally put the `sectionNameKeyPath` to something not nil resulting the cells being put into different sections.